# Server keeps creating processes with my php script

Tags: php, codeigniter, process

I am running a PHP script on a shared hosting server (hostgator). That PHP script is written with the `codeigniter` framework. Hostgator Shared hosting server only allows 25 processes to run. I have no idea why my script keeps creating the process on the server. The cpanel process server log looks like this:

```
2221    /usr/bin/php /home/megain/public_html/megainfine/index.php  0%  0.1%    Kill Process
30577   /usr/bin/php /home/megain/public_html/megainfine/index.php  0%  0.1%    Kill Process
30343   /usr/bin/php /home/megain/public_html/megainfine/index.php  0%  0.1%    Kill Process
29994   /usr/bin/php /home/megain/public_html/megainfine/index.php  0%  0.1%    Kill Process
32278   /usr/bin/php /home/megain/public_html/megainfine/index.php  0%  0.1%    Kill Process
28528   /usr/bin/php /home/megain/public_html/megainfine/index.php  0%  0.1%    Kill Process
27757   /usr/bin/php /home/megain/public_html/megainfine/index.php  0%  0.2%
```

The CUP Usage is almost 0% and Memory usage is only between 0.1-0.3%

Is this because of bad code?

Or, any idea why this process keeps getting created? I know that it will be hard to say without seeing my code, but I would like some general approach that will make the problem easier for me to trace.

---

Yes, I just asked the server support and they said they are using fastcgi. But the fact is that, they only allow 25 process maximum. Whenever it reach 25 process, I got internal server when browsing. And it very easily to got 25 process. So how can i do ? Can i do something from my scripting site ? I have run other scripts which is not mine like phpbb forum, but those processes are not appear in the processes. Please kindly suggest me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It might be that PHP scripts are run using [fastcgi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FastCGI). I believe when using this the web server will keep PHP processes running between requests for re-use, which is more efficient than starting a new one each time.

Answer (score 0):

This is rather unusual. Do you know the exact moment when these processes are created? Also, you should check your code for [ignore`_user_`abort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php) function and your php.ini for [ignore`_user_`abort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/misc.configuration.php#ini.ignore-user-abort) setting.